# Partial derivative of complex functions.

Tags: complex-analysis

I saw this in a complex analysis text $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z \, \partial\overline{z}}\log\frac{1}{1-|z|^2}=\frac{1}{(1-|z|^2)^2}$.

Can we treat $z, \bar{z}$ as independent variables, like what we did in

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x \, \partial y}\log\frac{1}{1-xy}=\frac{1}{(1-xy)^2}\text{ ?}$$

Comment: [Relevant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives)

Comment: Thanks. Columbus, using Wirtinger derivatives works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,  using Wirtinger derivatives explains why $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\overline{z}}\log\frac{1}{1-|z|^2}=\frac{1}{4}\left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} \right)\log\frac{1}{1-(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{1}{(1-(x^2+y^2))^2}=\frac{1}{(1-|z|^2)^2}.$